# Error:403 response for Boost HTTPS GET request

Tags: c++, boost, https, get, boost-asio

I have implemented a HTTPS client using boost::asio library, implementation went fine , yet the problem arises when I send a GET request that invokes some servlet like entity.

GET request

```
 request_stream << "GET "<<"https://172.198.71.135:8085/jrnal_content/test?data=MFBLUQ==&iv=aHU5Rw=="<<" HTTP/1.0\r\n"
```

The request was successfully written from my end to the server, but the response I have been getting is `403` ("Forbidden"), later sometime I sent another GET request.

```
 request_stream << "GET "<<"https://172.198.71.135:8085/users/Sign_in"<<" HTTP/1.0\r\n"
```

For which I've got `200`, I really do not know what went wrong in my first request (that received 403), I am sure there is no problem with certificate and stuff,I've never implemented an HTTP client/server before,so I want to make sure whether am making a proper request call.

Please see my code below

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service1;
    boost::asio::io_service &io_service(io_service1);
    boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
    boost::asio::ssl::context& context_=ctx;
    boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket_(io_service,context_);


int main()
{
    context_.set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds| boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2
        | boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
    context_.set_password_callback(my_password_callback);
    context_.use_certificate_chain_file("SSL\\rich.crt");
    context_.use_private_key_file("SSL\\rich.key", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
    boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
    tcp::resolver resolver_(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query("172.198.71.135", "https");
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver_.resolve(query);
    boost::asio::connect(socket_.lowest_layer(),endpoint_iterator);
    socket_.lowest_layer().set_option(tcp::no_delay(true));
    socket_.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer);
    socket_.set_verify_callback(boost::bind(verify_certificate));//(boost::asio::ssl::rfc2818_verification("172.198.71.135"));
    socket_.handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client);
                                      boost::asio::placeholders::error,                                           boost::asio::placeholders::iterator));
string path="https://172.198.71.135:8085/jrnal_content/test?";
     temp=path+"data="+data+"&"+"iv="+Iv;
     boost::asio::streambuf request;
     std::ostream request_stream(&request);
     request_stream << "GET "+temp+" HTTP/1.0\r\n" ;
     request_stream << "Host: " <<"172.198.71.135"<< "\r\n";
     request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
     request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
      const char* header=boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(request.data());
      cout<<header<<endl;
    try{
    boost::asio::write(socket_, request);
    request_stream.clear();
     t=sizeof(request);
    request.consume(t);
    }catch(runtime_error e)
    {   ss<<e.what();
        string err=ss.str();
        err="";
        ss.str("");

    }
    boost::asio::streambuf response;
    try{
    boost::asio::read_until(socket_, response, "\r\n");
    }catch(runtime_error e)
    {
        ss<<e.what();
        string err=ss.str();
        err="";
        ss.str("");
    }
    std::istream response_stream(&response);
    std::string http_version;
    response_stream >> http_version;
    unsigned int status_code;
    response_stream >> status_code;
    cout<<status_code<<"    status_code"<<endl;
    std::string status_message;
    std::getline(response_stream, status_message);
    if (!response_stream || http_version.substr(0, 5) != "HTTPS/")
    {

    }
    if (status_code==200)
    {
     ss<<ID;
     string SID=ss.str();
     ss.str("");
    boost::asio::read_until(socket_, response, "\r\n\r\n");
    response_stream.clear();
    t=sizeof(response);
    response.commit(t);
    }
    else{
    Sleep(6000);
    continue;

}
Sleep(7000);
}
 return 0;
}

 string my_password_callback(size_t t, boost::asio::ssl::context_base::password_purpose p)//std::size_t max_length,ssl::context::password_purpose purpose )
   {
    std::string password;
    return "12345";
   }

bool verify_certificate()
    {
    return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to sehe for the valuable suggestions he has given, So At last, I found what caused the issue.

```
tcp::resolver::query query("172.198.71.135", "https");
```

The above query gets resolved to 172.198.71.135:443 and the port NO 443 is blocked intentionally.

```
request_stream << "GET "<<"https://172.198.71.135:8085/jrnal_content/test?data=MFBLUQ==&iv=aHU5Rw=="<<" HTTP/1.0\r\n"
```

So things get changed as

tcp::resolver::query query("172.198.71.135", "https");

to

tcp::resolver::query query("172.198.71.135", "8085");

Answer (score 0):

The "three-digit mess" is what's commonly referred to as "a number". In this case, the number is [HTTP Status Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) of the webserver's response.

If you read up on "HTTP" and perhaps even that HTTP response code, you'll find that it means [Forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403):

> A web server may return a **403 Forbidden** HTTP status code in response to a request from a client for a web page or resource to indicate that the server can be reached and understood the request, but refuses to take any further action. Status code 403 responses are the result of the web server being configured to deny access, for some reason, to the requested resource by the client.

Make sure to supply the required [HTTP Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#HTTP_Authentication)

Comment: HI sehe, thanks for your reply yes i saw some HTTP request need authentication but in my case it won't need any authentication as the person running server has disabled it for me  though how it does work when i give request for sign_in  page it shouldn't work if basic authentication were enabled isn't it?

Comment: @RichardGeorge Talk to the guy. It's not disabled because the server sends 403 response. And no it makes little sense to suggest the login page itself requires basic auth. In fact, it makes no sense to have a login form **and** use basic authentication. I never said you require basic authentication. I meant supply the required Authentication (in general). That could be a session cookie. Etc.

Comment: So, talk to the guy to find out where the server is sending 403. Probably the server is just generating that expressly because of forms auth or whatever the app is using (Doesn't it strike you that there is a login form? At the very least you expect to _POST_ to that page with credentials, and receive a Set-Cookie header.)

Comment: About the login page page yes it struck me but the page i intended to access doesn't need any thing except basic authentication which was disabled now for my sake

Comment: @RichardGeorge clear some cookies... (or use an incognito tab)

Comment: Does cookies matter when we are sending HTTP request via Boost SSL socket ?

Comment: They matter when the server reads the request. Clients must pass the cookies when required. So the server decides when they "matter". In other words, coding a Web client is your job

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89166/discussion-between-sehe-and-richard-george).